# Address BY column in query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

How to access BY column in spreadsheet using query?

Background story:
this query:

```
=query(A1:BZ10,"select A,B,C where (BY> 1))",1)
```

causes unable to parse error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "by" "BY "" at line 2, column 16. Was expecting one of: "true" ... "false" ...

Reason for parse error is because BY is interpreted as BY from group by etc.

Comment: `=QUERY(A1:BZ10, "select A,B,C where \`BY\` > 1", 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## use `` ` `` instead of `()` like:

```
=QUERY(data!B2:CL, "select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, `BY`, BZ, CA, BA 
                    where J = 'Industry Certification'", 0)
```

[image: 3]